# Unable to telnet to Oracle service only from my client

Tags: linux, windows, oracle

I have installed Oracle 10gR2 on a linux box. And I am trying to access from my client. My client and the Oracle server are in two different networks and hence I got the access enabled in the Network Firewall for my client IP on that IP and port.

But I am unable to telnet to the Oracle server IP on that port. And on discussing with Network Security Firewall Team, they are getting deny messages from the server on accessing the port 1521 from the server.

```
telnet my_oracle_server_ip 1521
```

My Oracle service is running on 1521 port only. And I switched off the iptables, selinux on the Oracle server. I also switched off the firewall on my windows 7 client. Moreover, I found my colleague is able to access from his machine the database and tables of that Oracle server.

Could anyone please suggest where exactly the issue would be? Do I need to add my client IP anywhere in Oracle server's configuration file as in pg_hba.conf for postgresql?

Comment: Are you sure the listener (not just the service) is running on the server? And on the external IP, not localhost? Add the output of `lsnrctl status` to the question.

Comment: Thank you Alex for responding. I got the Oracle connected from my client but not sure what the reason is. But the issue is solved. Thank you anyways.